# What is the function of the parameter SegmentTimeline in the MPD files?

Tags: mpeg-dash

I look the differences between the SegmentTimeLines of a MPD and the next MPD but I don't know their function in a streaming live video.

For example, in Facebook Gaming I have this MPD:

https://video.fagp1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/hvideo-ash2-ftw/s3/v/rv2BbY6JOGDx9uSFI3pAo/live-dash/dash-abr6/2334520010097563.mpd?_nc_rl=AfASGXHXqR__Qe_w&oh=9b8743ae3dd255d8d4363515f7c07f2d&oe=5CDCDFAF

But I have a video content with different time like this:
https://video.fagp1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/hvideo-ash2-ftw/s3/v/rv2BbY6JOGDx9uSFI3pAo/live-dash/live-q1-v/2334520010097563_0-15243750.m4v

It could be problem of synchronization?

Comment: url has expiry token. Please attach a file